# issue with OnFocusChangeListener() in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a form for `member` registration in my android app, I have applied the `animation` effect on fields which are required (some `EditText` views in this case) if those fields are not filled the effect should occur then like this :

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mEditText.getText.equals("")) {
                mEditText.setAnimation(MyAnimation.animate());}
```

and `MyAnimation.animate()` is like :

```
public class MyAnimation {
public static Animation animate(){
    TranslateAnimation mAnimate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 5, 0, 0);
    mAnimate.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(50));
    mAnimate.setDuration(600);
    return mAnimate;
}
```

}

but the problem is it occurs when the `mEditText` gains the focus, and my need is this should occur on focus leave if `mEditText` is empty.

Comment: @Arsad Ali Soomro Check out my answer.

Comment: @GrIsHu thanks Im trying that